# How to verify if SDRAM alternative is a direct drop in replacement?

Tags: pcb, memory, component-selection, sdram

I'm trying to verify whether the two SDRAM chips are complete drop in replacements of each other. I've verified the footprint, electrical characteristics and various timing parameters (namely CL, tRCD, tRP, tRAS). However the datasheet for both are extensive and I'm out of my depth as to what else to verify. If someone could help me identify some other key parameters I should verify I would be very grateful. Thank you.

old: MT47H64M16NF-25E IT:M 
new: AS4C64M16D2A-25BINTR

Comment: Both SDRAMs are JEDEC Standard Compliant, so I would expect the timing parameters (as measured at the BGA) to be consistent between the chips. If I understand correctly, the JEDEC standard also dictates the command structure and memory transaction sequence for both chips. If you have verified footprint, internal memory arrangement, i/o voltage, maximum operating frequency, etc, I don't see another reason why it would not be a drop in replacement...